# Give element class when specific element has active class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible with Jquery to add another class to the .body element when the third li element has an .active class? It cant just add an class based on the .active class, it has to be the .active on the third li element specifically.

```
<div id="extendedinfobox">
   <ul class="prodtabmenu">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
<div class="body">
```

Comment: `if($(ul.prodtabmenu).find('li:nth-child(3).hasClass(active)')){$('body').addClass('body')}` try this one

Comment: `.addCla‌​ss('anotherclass')` :)

Comment: nth-child(3) is the key here

Answer (score 4):

https://jsfiddle.net/sn2nc9bd/1/

```
if($('ul.prodtabmenu').find('li:nth-child(3)').hasClass('active'))
{
   $('.body').addClass('newClass');   
}
```

Comment: you might need a jsfiddle edit, it doesn't look right. EDIT nvm i see you were just following his directions adding a class to the body

Comment: I already edited my comment, but I thought it was wrong because I misunderstood he wanted to add a class to the *body* as a result of the selection. your class to add to the body had a height of 10px, so it looked like a misplaced line highlight. my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

```js
if ($('ul.prodtabmenu').find('li:nth-child(3)').hasClass('active')) {
  //$('body').addClass('disabled');
  $('.body').addClass('disabled');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="extendedinfobox">
  <ul class="prodtabmenu">
    <li>2</li>
    <li>21</li>
    <li class="active">3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="body">
```

Try like this

Use [.nth-child()](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

> Description: Selects all elements that are the nth-child of their parent.

use `.nth-child(3)` to select the 3rd `li`

Comment: "to add another class to the .body element"

Comment: @Andy i am just showing how to add class to the 3rd li. he can always change that.. i change it anyway

Comment: The OP doesn't want the class added to the 3rd `li` element. He wants it on the element with the `.body` class.

Comment: You might also want `$('ul.prodtabmenu')` to target that particular `ul`.